# my table is dropped in PDO

Tags: php, sql-injection

This  is my `PDO` method i used this method to save input value to `SQL` After reading this [pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection?lq=1)  Since Am started learning `PHP` i don't know this will protect form SQL injection

### CODE

```
    <?php

$db_username = 'sanoj';
$db_password = '123456';
$newname = md5(rand() * time());
if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
    $uploadedFiles = array();
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
        $errors = array();
        $file_name = md5(uniqid("") . time());
        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];

        if ($file_type == "image/gif") {
            $sExt = ".gif";
        } elseif ($file_type == "image/jpeg" || $file_type == "image/pjpeg") {
            $sExt = ".jpg";
        } elseif ($file_type == "image/png" || $file_type == "image/x-png") {
            $sExt = ".png";
        }
        if (!in_array($sExt, array('.gif', '.jpg', '.png'))) {
            $errors[] = "Image types alowed are (.gif, .jpg, .png) only!";
        }
        if ($file_size > 2097152000) {
            $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }
        $desired_dir = "user_data/";
        if (empty($errors)) {
            if (is_dir($desired_dir) == false) {
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $file_name . $sExt)) {
                $uploadedFiles[$key] = array($file_name . $sExt, 1);
            } else {
                echo "Couldn't upload file " . $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
                $uploadedFiles[$key] = array($_FILES['files']['name'][$key], 0);
            }
        } else {

        }
    }

    foreach ($uploadedFiles as $key => $row) {
        if (!empty($row[1])) {
            $codestr = '$file' . ($key + 1) . ' = $row[0];';
            eval($codestr);
        } else {
            $codestr = '$file' . ($key + 1) . ' = NULL;';
            eval($codestr);
        }
    }
}
$orig_directory = "$desired_dir";    //Full image folder
$thumb_directory = "thumb/";    //Thumbnail folder

/* Opening the thumbnail directory and looping through all the thumbs: */
$dir_handle = @opendir($orig_directory); //Open Full image dirrectory
if ($dir_handle > 1) { //Check to make sure the folder opened
    $allowed_types = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
    $file_type = array();
    $ext = '';
    $title = '';
    $i = 0;

    while ($file_name = @readdir($dir_handle)) {
        /* Skipping the system files: */
        if ($file_name == '.' || $file_name == '..')
            continue;

        $file_type = explode('.', $file_name);    //This gets the file name of the images
        $ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_type));

        /* Using the file name (withouth the extension) as a image title: */
        $title = implode('.', $file_type);
        $title = htmlspecialchars($title);

        /* If the file extension is allowed: */
        if (in_array($ext, $allowed_types)) {

            /* If you would like to inpute images into a database, do your mysql query here */

            /* The code past here is the code at the start of the tutorial */
            /* Outputting each image: */

            $nw = 100;
            $nh = 100;
            $source = "$desired_dir{$file_name}";
            $stype = explode(".", $source);
            $stype = $stype[count($stype) - 1];
            $dest = "thumb/{$file_name}";

            $size = getimagesize($source);
            $w = $size[0];
            $h = $size[1];

            switch ($stype) {
                case 'gif':
                    $simg = imagecreatefromgif($source);
                    break;
                case 'jpg':
                    $simg = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
                    break;
                case 'png':
                    $simg = imagecreatefrompng($source);
                    break;
            }

            $dimg = resizePreservingAspectRatio($simg, $nw, $nh);
            imagepng($dimg, $dest);
        }
    }

    /* Closing the directory */
    @closedir($dir_handle);
}

try {
#connection 
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=localtest', $db_username, $db_password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $data = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO agriculture (cacat, mtype, mtitle, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, description, mcondition, cmodel, price, youare, mname, email, phone, ylocation, ystreet) VALUES (:cacat, :mtype, :mtitle, :image1, :image2, :image3, :image4, :image5, :description, :mcondition, :cmodel, :price, :youare, :mname, :email, :phone, :ylocation, :ystreet)');
    $cacat = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cacat', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
    $mtype = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mtype', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
    $mtitle = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mtitle', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
    $description = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'description', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
    $mcondition = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mcondition', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
    $cmodel = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cmodel', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
    $price = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'price', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
    $youare = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'youare', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
    $mname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
    $phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'phone', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
    $ylocation = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ylocation', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
    $ystreet = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ystreet', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
    $data->execute(array(':cacat' => $cacat,
        ':mtype' => $mtype,
        ':mtitle' => $mtitle,
        'image1' => $file1,
        'image2' => $file2,
        'image3' => $file3,
        'image4' => $file4,
        'image5' => $file5, ':description' => $description, ':mcondition' => $mcondition, ':cmodel' => $cmodel, ':price' => $price, ':youare' => $youare, ':mname' => $mname, ':email' => $email, ':phone' => $phone, ':ylocation' => $ylocation, ':ystreet' => $ystreet));
#exception handiling
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

function resizePreservingAspectRatio($img, $targetWidth, $targetHeight) {
    $srcWidth = imagesx($img);
    $srcHeight = imagesy($img);

    // Determine new width / height preserving aspect ratio
    $srcRatio = $srcWidth / $srcHeight;
    $targetRatio = $targetWidth / $targetHeight;
    if (($srcWidth <= $targetWidth) && ($srcHeight <= $targetHeight)) {
        $imgTargetWidth = $srcWidth;
        $imgTargetHeight = $srcHeight;
    } else if ($targetRatio > $srcRatio) {
        $imgTargetWidth = (int) ($targetHeight * $srcRatio);
        $imgTargetHeight = $targetHeight;
    } else {
        $imgTargetWidth = $targetWidth;
        $imgTargetHeight = (int) ($targetWidth / $srcRatio);
    }

    // Creating new image with desired size
    $targetImg = imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth, $targetHeight);

    // Add transparency if your reduced image does not fit with the new size
    $targetTransparent = imagecolorallocate($targetImg, 255, 0, 255);
    imagefill($targetImg, 0, 0, $targetTransparent);
    imagecolortransparent($targetImg, $targetTransparent);

    // Copies image, centered to the new one (if it does not fit to it)
    imagecopyresampled($targetImg, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $targetWidth, $targetHeight, $srcWidth, $srcHeight);

    return $targetImg;
}

?>
```

**experts said there is security issue while uploading image `basename`**
Can some one help me will this protect from SQL injection

Comment: Question is better suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: What’s the meaning of your question title?

Comment: @Gumbo i have added my code, I used above to store user input and image now some one dropped my table

Comment: [bobby drop tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 1):

Just to confuse you further...

IMHO filter_input() is a very bad solution to a dangerous problem.

It doesn't just filter input, it frequently transforms it as well. And you should never transform input. By the time the data is available to PHP, then it is too late to fix anything which might be toxic to PHP.

Whenever data **leaves** PHP then it should be transformed to an appropriate representation *depending on where the data is going*. E.g. using quoted_printable(), htmlentities(), urlencode().... But note that mysqli_real_escape_string() function requires a valid database handle to transform data - the reason for this is that there is no generic solution for transforming data going into a MySQL database. Hence any attempt at transforming data without reference to the database will not be totally secure.

(In your case, using a prepared statement with PDO addresses the issue of transforming the data - the point I am trying to make is that filter_input() cannot possibly provide a complete solution).

Since the representation of the data should exclusively be based on where it is going from PHP, it makes no sense to transform *input*. Only *output* should be transformed.

Another problem with filter_input() is that it does not differentiate between validation and transformation. There are scenarios where your code should reject the supplied data - validation. This should be applied to input data before it is processed.

i.e. you should:

***Validate input. Transform output.***

And one thing you should never do is to transform the output of a transformation.

You have done this in your code with both filter_input() and bound parameters. It is why 'magic_quotes' have been deprecated in PHP for a long time.

```
tranform(transform(data)) != transform(data)
```

Comment: can you please correct my code above so that i can learn `mysql_real_escape_string` is Deprecated and am little confused about it, how could i store input value to `SQL` in secure method